# GeoServer - disk quota error

Tags: geoserver, docker, permission

I was able to dockerize the GeoServer (KARTOZA image) into an AWS ECS CLUSTER, to which I have attached an EFS volume; inside the EFS is sitting the data dir `/opt/geoserver_data/data_dir`.

I noticed that as more layers were created into the GeoServer, the new deployments started getting broken due to the number of files inside the `GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR` folder. To fix that, I removed the line which gives permission to the `GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR` folder.

- commented line:

`chown -R "${USER_NAME}":"${GEO_GROUP_NAME}"  "${GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR}"`

Once I removed the above permission I got another error, now on the disk quota.

- Error:

`Loading quota store failed, the disk quota subsystem is disabled, please re-configure: Could not open JDBC Connection for transaction; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (General error: java.lang.RuntimeException: double allocation in file /opt/geoserver_data/data_dir/gwc/diskquota_page_store_h2/diskquota.index.db page 187 blocks 11968-12031 [50000-119])`

[image]

Is this error related to the permissions that I removed from the Geoserver?

I already set the permission for `sudo chmod 777 GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR`to try to fix this issue, but no success so far.

Comment: Don't mess with ownership or permissions. Go back to the original issue and fix it correctly. Too many files in the data directory should not be a problem, unless it is too small

Comment: That's the question @ian , how to fix the disk quota issue?

Answer (score 3):

I think I found the solution.
To fix this issue I followed these steps:

- Disabled the check box for disk quota
- Delete the file `diskquota.index.db` on folder `gwc/diskquota_page_store_h2`
- Enable the check box for disk quota again

Doing those steps a new file will be generated on the folder.

[image]

Comment: The H2 disk quota subsystem is easy to use but not the most reliable. If you can switch to a disk quota stored in PostgreSQL instead.

Comment: Thanks @DougP, this helped me.